# How can i disable props checking when jsx type is a function?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

when i set the `jsx` to `react` and `jsxFactory` to `fn` in tsconfig.json,
and some errors here:

a.tsx

```js
import fn from "./fn";
import delegate from "./delegate";

class A {
    constructor(point: { x: number, y: number }){
        console.log(x, y);

        // ...
    }
}

delegate(
    <A target={document.getElementById("myId")} />
);
```

delegate.ts

```js
export default function delegate({ type, props: { target } }){
    target.onClick = (e) => {
        new type(e.clickX, e.clickY);
    };
};
```

The errors:`Type '{ target: HTMLElement; }' is not assignable to type '{ x: number;, y: number; }'` and `Property 'target' does not exist on type '{ x: number; y: number; }'`

how can i disable the props checking ?
Do not care the logic with code, because, this only is an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can assert the props as `any` and then spread (`...`) them:

```
delegate(
    <A {...({ target: document.getElementById("myId") } as any)} />
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The code is below:

`jsx-namespace.d.ts`

```js
declare namespace JSX {
     // ...
    interface IntrinsicAttributes {
        [attributeName: string]: any
    }
    // ...
}
```

for `typescript 3.4.5`